# What does "induced operations" means in congruence operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, congruence-relations

It says: prove that R is a congruence (it means it's a relation of equivalence and it preserves operations) ith respect to sum and multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$.

$a,b\in \mathbb{R}: aRb \iff a-b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

This is the problem of my question -> "Describe the induced operations in ${\mathbb{R}}/{R}$. Also what are their properties?"

I have a counterexample for multiplication, meaning this isn't a congruence respect to multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$, am I right?

What is the meaning of "induced operations" and how can I find them all, does square a number counts as operation?, how can I be sure i've found them all?.

Answer (score -1):

For *congruence* or an *equivalence* relation, you need 3 properties:

- reflexive ($aRa$)
- symmetric ($aRb \Leftrightarrow bRa$)
- transitive ($aRb, bRc \Rightarrow aRc$)

In your case, $a-a=0 \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, so $R$ is reflexive.

If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a - b \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $b-a = -(a-b) \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $R$ is symmetric.

Can you prove $R$ is transitive?

Comment: My definition of congruence is that it is a relation of equivalence, and it prserves operations (in this case sum and multiplication), I can prove its a relation of equivalence, but i cna't prove it preserves multiplication.
But the real question is: what is the meaning of Induced operations and how can i find em all. 
Thank you for answering.